# Parsing a JSON with a missing parameter

Tags: json, swift, struct

Im getting a JSON from a webpage, where i get the weather for an airport, and so far so good, it works, but one is

```
struct MetarResponse: Codable {

var windGust = Windgust

}

struct WindGust: Codable {
    var repr: String?
}
```

sometimes when it comes from the JSON i will give me

```
"wind_gust":{"repr":"37","value":37,"spoken":"three seven"},
```

But if this value is not present in the weather, it will give me

> "wind_gust":null,

so right now i have the problem, that i only need to use repr value, and that does work with the Struct i have, but it crashes the app when i get the weather at a place that contains null instead.

How do i prevent it from crashing when i try to parse the JSON?

working code:

```
struct MetarResponse: Codable {

var windGust = Windgust?

}

struct WindGust: Codable {
    var repr: String?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `WindGust` struct optional, something like

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    let windGust: WindGust?
}
```

Example

```
let data = """
    {"wind_gust":null}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

do {
    let weather = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: data)
    print(weather.windGust)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code since there where a mistake, and i wrote the code as it is now working, with your suggestion, i was mistakenly convinced that i could not use that ? in that position.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check if you are getting what you want and provide a custom value so your system won't crash. Something like:

```
struct WindGust: Codable {
    var repr: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case repr
    }
}


extension WindGust: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let repr = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) else {
             repr = "placeholder"
             return
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can manage when your json data aren't as you would expect, I haven't tried the code above, but hopefully you can get the idea.
I also recommend [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) documentation by Apple.